# Why is klass needed in this code?

Tags: ruby

```
    def record
      return unless @supported

      klasses = profile_options[:formats].map { |f| RubyProf.const_get("#{f.to_s.camelize}Printer") }.compact

      klasses.each do |klass|
        fname = output_filename(klass)
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(fname))
        File.open(fname, 'wb') do |file|
          klass.new(@data).print(file, profile_options.slice(:min_percent))
        end
      end
    end
```

I understand that 'klass' is used to prevent namespace conflicts with the keyword 'class' but why would either 'klass' or 'class' be needed in this code (from Rails::ActiveSupport) - what purpose do they serve? What is klass used for here? Or, if class were used instead, why would it be needed? What's klass/class for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`class` is a keyword to define classes. `klass` is simply a name given to a local variable, which would have been called `class` if it wasn't for the fact that you can't name a local variable `class`. There is no special significance to the name `klass` for variables other than that it looks like `class`.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is for readability. When you have a long chunk of code, it sometimes helps to name at some intermediate steps it even if it is going to be used only once.